# Tikz pgf plot: cyclic shift of alphabetic labels on x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have the following code to produce a plot

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
  letter & freq  \\
  a      & 11 \\
  b      & 0  \\
  c      & 4  \\
  d      & 3  \\
  e      & 11 \\
  f      & 7  \\
  g      & 1  \\
  h      & 1  \\
  i      & 11 \\
  j      & 5  \\
  k      & 3  \\
  l      & 0  \\
  m      & 2  \\
  n      & 6  \\
  o      & 9  \\
  p      & 3  \\
  q      & 0  \\
  r      & 6  \\
  s      & 4  \\
  t      & 5  \\
  u      & 3  \\
  v      & 2  \\
  w      & 10 \\
  x      & 7  \\
  y      & 11 \\
  z      & 9  \\     }\alph 

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.44,every node/.style={scale=0.44}]
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=.25cm,
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z},
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style={text height=2ex}
      ]
      \addplot[green,fill=green] table[x=letter,y=freq]{\alph};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to rotate cyclically the columns (without doing it manually).

My ultimate goal is to produce a new command `\shift` such that `\shift{e}`  (or `\shift{4}`) would produce the figure equivalent to the given code with

```
symbolic x coords={e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,a,b,c,d},
```

Comment: the alphabet generation is rather easy but do you want to sort the data accordingly too?

Comment: Yes: the shift should apply both to the labels on the x axis and their values

Comment: The data will follow the order given in the table. You have to sort the table too. Is that an option?

Comment: @percusse: please forgive me but I can't understand what you mean. If you take the code and substitute the `x coords` line with the other line I wrote in the question (and without touching the table), then you get a completely different plot. That is: the letter `d` goes in the last position and its value is still 3 as in the original plot. The same applies to all other letters: they are shifted accordingly but they keep the same value in the plot.

Comment: Ah no it's my mistake. I haven't tested before I tried it with actual code. Let me type something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can already use `pgffor` facilities to cycle through the (english) alphabet in a compact fashion. The macro is not fully expandable though I just made something that works.

You might want to avoid using macro names such `\alph` etc. because they are usually used by well-known packages and even LaTeX itself.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\def\cyclicalph#1{\if#1a\def\zzz{a,...,z}\else\def\zzz{#1,...,z,a,b,...,#1}\fi%
  \gdef\mylist{}%
  \foreach\x[count=\xi]in\zzz{%
    \ifnum\xi>26\else%
      \expandafter\xdef\expandafter\mylist\expandafter{%
        \mylist\x\ifnum\xi=26 \else,\fi%
      }%
    \fi%
  }%
}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
  letter & freq  \\
  a      & 11 \\  b      & 0  \\  c      & 4  \\
  d      & 3  \\  e      & 11 \\  f      & 7  \\
  g      & 1  \\  h      & 1  \\  i      & 11 \\
  j      & 5  \\  k      & 3  \\  l      & 0  \\
  m      & 2  \\  n      & 6  \\  o      & 9  \\
  p      & 3  \\  q      & 0  \\  r      & 6  \\
  s      & 4  \\  t      & 5  \\  u      & 3  \\
  v      & 2  \\  w      & 10 \\  x      & 7  \\
  y      & 11 \\  z      & 9  \\     }\myalph 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.44,every node/.style={scale=0.44}]

\cyclicalph{e} %<---- Set the cycle somewhere before the axis. 
               % It will set the `\mylist` macro

    \begin{axis}[
        ybar=0pt,
        bar width=.25cm,
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        symbolic x coords/.expand once=\mylist,% Use it here 
        xtick=data,
        xticklabel style={text height=2ex}
      ]
      \addplot[green,fill=green] table[x=letter,y=freq]{\myalph};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used `\alph` just in this example: in my file it is a different name. Nice!