# Use symbolic x coords with variable

Tags: graphics, plot

I'm working on a Latex project and I have to make some graphics.

In one of them, I need in the X axis to display some month of the year. For a test, I used :  Aout,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec When I write it directly in the Latex file, it is working. But I need it to be dynamic, I want to use it with a variable.

```
\def \test{Aout,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec}

\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
              symbolic x coords = {\test},
              ]
              \addplot[] ... 

\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Any idea how I can do it ?

Comment: Use `/.expand once`. Similar questions [using variables or commands in pgfplots axis definitions - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313175/using-variables-or-commands-in-pgfplots-axis-definitions/314498#314498) ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299237/tikz-pgf-plot-cyclic-shift-of-alphabetic-labels-on-x-axis/299277#299277 ; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153853/pgfplots-how-to-load-distinct-symbolic-ticks-labels-from-file/153971#153971 -- if that does not solve the question to make the easier to answer post a MWE.

Comment: Ho yes ! It is working thank you so much !!